# React Native Firebase with user session timeout (Active User)

Tags: firebase, react-native, session, timeout, report

I search the official website and know that a default session timeout is 30 minutes. I want to change it to be 5minutes because i want to count an active user after 5 minutes only.

I cannot find any method to edit the session timeout in firebase dashboard. Can anyone help?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and it's hard to say what your actual goal is. Are you trying to [implement a presence system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-sample) on Firebase?

Comment: Want website to have some user login session with the average of staying in the screen. Therefore, i need to define the active user with session timeout to 5minns